# How to insert data into database from wavemaker

Tags: database, insert, dml

I want to insert data from wavemaker into database which will be inserted by user at runtime. But didnt get yet how to do it in wavemaker.

Can anyone please suggest me a simple example of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really easy to do with WaveMaker.  I suggest you follow the [2nd Tutorial](http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmdoc_6.4/IntroTutorial), which shows how to import a DB schema and quickly build a UI to insert data into a DB.

Comment: But what if I dont want to use default layout to display data? On my page,there is one sample registration form on left side with two buttons - Submit and Reset.And data should be inserted in two different tables when user click on submit button. For this I cant used that default layout.Whats the better way to do this?

Comment: If you are inserting data into two different tables, you will need two live forms. Hide the edit panel buttons for each live form and create your own submit/reset buttons. Clicking submit button should call javascript function that in turn calls liveFormFoo.insertData(). More info on this [here](http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmjsref_6.4/LiveForm_insertData)

Comment: link is now broken